# Can the ergm/statnet package deal with missing attribute data?

Tags: r, sna, statnet

Just starting out with ERGM so apologies if the following question is not logical. I have tried to search on this site, and statnet_help, with no luck.

I was wondering whether the ergm() function in statnet can now cope with missing data on attributes? I have coded it as 'na' in R but running the following ergm model resulted in an error.

```
    > m2 <- ergm(d1~edges + nodecov('wellbeing')) 

    > Error in ergm.getglobalstats(nw, model, response = response) : 
    > NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 13)
```

The attribute variable in question is continuous.

Many thanks,
S

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is possible to have `NA`s on edge/node covariates. It is not very clear how should they be treated anyway. Depending on your interests in tracing the importance of nodes with missing data you might try:

- Imputing `NA`s with some sensible values (even a mean)
- Adding a binary covariate equal to 1 for `NA` and 0 otherwise and using it in `nodecov` and perhaps some other effects to check whether there is any evidence for these nodes to have some special role in the network structure.